# mail routing connection testing

Tags: monitoring, exchange-2010, powershell

I would like to implement an alerting process that will send a test email to an internet based mail server every 5 minutes, I manually email echo@esat.net if I suspect there is a transmission issue with our email.. So I would to automate this, but I don't want to have to monitor a mailbox every 10 minutes to see if there is a delay, I want to be alerted if I do not get a response after 10 - 15 mins

I currently have a exchange 2003 mail infrastructure but we are moving to 2010 in the next few weeks and would like to have this alerting system in place, as a first line of notification of an issue hopefully before a user does.

Is this possible with a powershell script.

Comment: Many system monitoring solutions have email loop test capability. What do you use to monitor your systems?

Comment: We currently use nagios to monitor systems, but im not sure it could be setup to check this email loop.